# Uable to get JSON in cloud function callback android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on Parse platform (Parse.com) in which I have a cloud code function written below which returns me proper JSON response in result -

Cloud function -

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getBranchbyUniversityID", function(request, response) {
        var branchList = { Branch: [] };
        var universityID = request.params.UniversityID;
        console.log("University ID received " + universityID);
        var TableBranch = Parse.Object.extend("TableBranch");
        var query = new Parse.Query(TableBranch);
        query.equalTo("UniversityId", universityID);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                var branchDetails_length = results.length;
                console.log("branchDetails_length " + branchDetails_length);
                if (branchDetails_length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < branchDetails_length; i++) {
                        var branchName = results[i].get("BranchName");                              
                        var branchID = results[i].get("BranchId");
                        branchList.Branch.push({ 
                        "BranchName" : branchName,
                        "BranchId" : branchID
                        });
                        }
                }
                response.success(branchList);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                response.error("Could not connect to server");
            }
        });
});
```

Result that i get in my parse log console

```
    {
 "Branch":[
  {
   "BranchName":"Civil",
   "BranchId":"2"
  },
  {
   "BranchName":"ComputerScience",
   "BranchId":"1"
  }
 ]
}
```

My Android code to call cloud function "getBranchbyUniversityID"

```
String uniId = "1";

Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("UniversityID",uniId);

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getBranchbyUniversityID", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Object response, ParseException e) {
       LoggingUtil.log("Response for BranchDetails", response.toString());

    }
});
```

This is what my log console print in android

```
Response for BranchDetails﹕ {Branch=[{BranchName=Civil, BranchId=2}, {BranchName=ComputerScience, BranchId=1}]}
```

The response i am getting is not in the form of JSON but i can see in the parse console the Result is in JSON as mentioned above.

I also tried also tried calling cloud function like

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getBranchbyUniversityID", params, new FunctionCallback<JSONObject>()
```

but this also did not worked it was giving class exception.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong or is it the SDK problem ?

Comment: The response object is a HashMap.

Comment: Where you ever able to solve this? I am running into the same issue.